# How to replace 1st match of regex pattern, leave others alone

Tags: c#, regex

With C#, how do I replace only the first match of something?

**Example input**: `<img src="1.jpg" />some other text<img src="2.jpg" />`

**Regex I'm using, which works**: 
`<img.*?>`

The following replaces all matches, but, I just want to replace the first one and leave the 2nd one (and all others) alone.

```
string val = Regex.Replace(input, "<img.*?>", string.Empty);
return val;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the overloaded [Regex.Replace Method (String, MatchEvaluator, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e47f3dkc.aspx)

Set the value of the Int32 to 1.

Answer (score 3):

Pass `1` as the third parameter.

`Regex.Replace` has [an overload that takes a maximum number of replacements to make](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx).

---

Note that you can achieve substantially better performance by putting a `Regex` instance in a static readonly field.  This way, the runtime won't need to re-parse the regex every time you call `Replace`.